# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я явно объявляю переменную `groups` как массив, но выдаёт ошибку `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```js
const typeObject = require('./typeObject')


async function getTreeHtml(group_number, data, tree_html){
    if(await typeObject(data[group_number]) === 'array'){
        for(let i = 0; i < data[group_number].length; i++){
            const row = data[group_number][i]
            const array_name = row[3] + "otdel7707"
            if(group_number === '-otdel7707'){
                tree_html += '<ul class="tree">'
            }else{
                tree_html += '<ul>'
            }

            tree_html += '<li>'
            tree_html += '<code>'
            tree_html += row[5]
            tree_html += '<hr />'

            let groups = []

            for(let x = 0; x < data[array_name].length; x++){
                const el = data[array_name][x]
                if(!groups.includes(el[3] + 'otdel7707')){
                    groups.push(el[3] + 'otdel7707')
                }
                tree_html += el[2]
                if(x !== data[array_name].length - 1){
                    tree_html += '<br />'
                }
            }
            tree_html += '</code>'
            for(let x = 0; x < groups.length; x++){
                const group_name = groups[x]
                tree_html += await getTreeHtml(group_name, data, "")
            }



            if(i === data[group_number].length - 1){
                tree_html += '</li>'
            }
        }
        tree_html += '</ul>'
    }


    return tree_html
}

module.exports = getTreeHtml
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся. Node.js не перестаёт меня удивлять после PHP, но как язык считаю, что он более гибкий

Comment: уверенны, что это для groups ошибка? так то вроде должно работать

Comment: почему ты решил, что проблема связана с `groups`?

Comment: Когда комментирую `for` с `length`, то есть последний `for`, то скрипт отрабатывает

Comment: @Alexandr извиняюсь, забыл ник прикрепить

Comment: @Grundy ответил ниже

Comment: @Vladislav Sokolov tree_html += await getTreeHtml(group_name, data, "") в этой функции тоже есть .length   если одну эту строку закоментишь тоже будет срабатывать, короче не факт, что это именно этот цикл

Comment: добавь информацию об ошибке скриншотом, там указано в каком именно месте произошла ошибка

Comment: @Alexandr большое спасибо! Буду дальше разбираться почему ошибка возникает. Значит где-то в `data` ошибся. И снова, большое спасибо)

Comment: @Vladislav Sokolov tree_html += await getTreeHtml(group_name, data, "") могу предположить что data тут пустая, и при рекурсии получаешь ошибку просто на первом for(let x = 0; x < data[array_name].length; x++)

Comment: @Grundy выше уже ответили. Видимо беда в `data` https://youtu.be/HkvmIYzuU-Q Видео ещё заливается. @Alexandr

Comment: @Alexandr Дата точно не пустая. Ибо некоторая информация выводится, как видно на видео. Буду перепроверять

Comment: @Grundy @Alexandr добавил проверку перед вторым `for` всё заработало

Comment: @VladislavSokolov, ты неправильно проверяешь. Если это у тебя серверный код, выведи лог и посмотри что и чему у тебя равно в какой момент. Либо как минимум оберни все в `try..catch` и верни текст ошибки со стектрейсом

Comment: @Vladislav Sokolov  а вам не что-то нужно, а data[array_name].length где array_name = row[3] + "otdel7707" где row = data[group_number][i]   , миллион факторов должно сработать, чтоб запустилось без ошибки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const array_name = row[3] + "otdel7707";
if (!data[array_name])
  continue;
```